# How to extract .NET project references into a separate file?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

So, my general setup right now goes like this: 
I have a large framework thing that is accessible to me and is used as a way of monetization. In the same solution, I have Xamarin.Android app that uses that exact framework. I had to do this because the framework is being developed alongside the Android application and doing NuGet reference management or recompiling .dll every time is not an option.

There is another solution inside this large project that only references Xamarin.Android app project. But the difference is, this Android project uses the same exact .cs files and all that but has what is essentially a copy of .csproj file from the larger solution.

The difference between them is: one uses direct references to projects inside the solution and other references .dll files that are generated by the larger solution. This is required because the client should have access to the smaller application, but not to the framework.

I now understand that this solution with two .csproj files is faulty by design because when I add or remove any file, I have to remove it in two places and the question is: what is the better way to handle references in that Android project?

Comment: Use a "shared code" project and reference that to the two other projects

Comment: @SushiHangover you're referring to "Shared Project", as in, a project that doesn't have references and doesn't produce .dll? This would require a lot of structural changes in the project and it will be hard to explain to the client, because he cannot see the second project. I'm looking for a solution that would allow me to have only one .csproj, any ideas on this?

Comment: Would it be an option to create a separate file (e. g. `common.stuff`) and within the two `csproj` files, call `<import Project="common.stuff" />` ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019))?

Comment: @mu88 wow, I didn't know about this mechanism! This is all I need, with this "Condition" attribute and two new build configurations to be good to go. Thank you very much! Could you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build system MSBuild is quite flexible and allows you to do a lot of stuff, e. g. loading properties from other files. Just open an existing `csproj` file and search for `<Import Project="`. [Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019) allows you to load whatever you need from another file - may it be a dumb MSBuild property or adding a file with `<Compile Include="Class1.cs" />`. And both Visual Studio and MSBuild are taking care about this.

Based on this, your solution could look like this:

Common file `common.props`:

```cs
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
</ItemGroup>
<Compile Include="SharedClass1.cs" />
<Compile Include="SharedClass2.cs" />
```

At the beginning of every consuming `csproj` file:

```cs
<Import Project="common.props" Condition="Exists('common.props')" />
```

Now you can add new shared settings (files, properties, etc.) to `common.stuff` and automatically, all projects will get them as well. Unfortunately, I don't think that you can manage this via the native Visual Studio way like *Add → New Item...*, so you have to do this by hand. But at least you should be able to add `common.stuff` to your Solution so that you don't have to switch applications (e. g. to Notepad++).

Comment: I already do a lot of prebuild scripting and .csproj modifications, so this shouldn't be a problem. Thanks again!